# Cursor moving on main page instead of clicked pop up window?

Tags: extjs

In pop up window functionality, when pop up window is appeared after clicking over a link. When i press tab the cursor is moving on to main page instead of pop up window. Until i manually click over the pop up window. Is there any property to set in extjs,so that cursor control is over pop up window whenever the link is clicked instead of main window.

Comment: this is a browser design, it will behave differently on different browsers.

Comment: How can this be resolved ?any ideas?

Comment: does the pop-up need to have modal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually give focus to the popup window, if you opened the popup like so:

```
var popup = window.open('http://google.com','window','height=500,width=300');
```

Then you can focus it with the following line:

```
if(window.focus) { popup.focus(); }
```

Comment: This should give him the right idea.  The only thing different that I would do is put the focus on a specific field or element that the user might typically interact with.